# How to use fetch() and echo in php

Tags: php, html

I am new to php and I cant seem to figure out what is wrong. The following gives me an output of "(link)file_name.jpg(link)file_id.jpg" when I need it to output "file_name.jpg (link)file_id.jpg" the (link part means the following is a link) thanks!

```
                    $view_uploads_sql = $db->prepare("SELECT file_name, file_id FROM uploads WHERE owner_id = ?");
                    $view_uploads_sql->execute(array($_SESSION['memberID']));

                    $upload_array = $view_uploads_sql->fetch();
                    echo array_values($t);
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($upload_array); $i++)
                    {
                       echo "<a href = 'uploads/$upload_array[$i]'>$upload_array[$i]</a>";
                    }
```

Comment: `fetch` just returns one row. Did you mean to use `fetchAll`?

Answer (score 0):

`fetch()` just returns the next row of results from the query, not all of them. You have to call it in a loop, or use `fetchAll()` to fetch everything.

```
$upload_array = $view_uploads_sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($upload_array as $row) {
    echo "<a href='uploads/{$row['file_name']}'>{$row['file_id']}</a>";
}
```

And notice that if you want to use an expression in the subsscript when substituting an array element into a string, you need to put `{}` around it.

Comment: now its says PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file_id and PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file_name even though those are the fields in the mysql db

Comment: Sorry, those should be `$row`.